# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan( [-\pi^2]x^2)- \tan^2( [-\pi^2]x^2)}{\sin^2x}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, limits-without-lhopital

**[.] is Greatest Integer Function**

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\tan( 10x^2) + \tan ^2 (10x^2)}{\sin^2 x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\tan 10x^2)(\tan 10 x^2 -1)}{\sin^2x}$$
$$=10 \lim_{x\to 0} \tan 10 x^2 -1$$
$$=-10$$

The right answer is $\tan 10 -10$

Can I please get my solution verified

Comment: That $x^2$ isn't in the argument of the second $\tan^2$ function.

Comment: Yes, your steps and he answer, both are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lfloor -\pi^2\rfloor = -10$, the given function is $$\frac{\tan(-10x^2) - \tan^2(-10x^2)}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{-\tan 10x^2 - (-\tan 10x^2)^2}{\sin^2 x} = - \frac{(1 + \tan 10x^2)\tan 10x^2}{\sin^2 x}.$$  You did not correctly compute the second term in the numerator, forgetting that the negative is squared.  However, this does not affect the value of the limit that you computed.

---

For your other question, note $$\frac{\tan(-10x^2) - \tan(-10) x^2}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x} \tan 10 - \frac{\sin(10x^2)}{\sin^2 x} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos(10x^2)}.$$  We know $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.  How would you evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin (10x^2)}{\sin^2 x}?$$  There are multiple ways to do this.  I leave this to you as an exercise.

Comment: Can I get one a solution for a slight variation of this question I thought of $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan( [-\pi^2]x^2)- \tan( [-\pi^2])x^2}{\sin^2x}$